# Scrollable menu with fixed position

Tags: jquery, html, css

Yes, I know, this question have been asked many times and I have read all the posts. Unfortunately, suggested solutions don't work in my case. I have a fixed position topbar with several hidden menus that appear when clicking on the link. The menus are of fixed position as well.

I need these menus to be scroolable if they don't fit in the window. At the same time I would like to disable the scrollbal and scrolling of the main window if a menu is open.

In Jsfiddle example Menu1 doesn't fit in the window and needs a scroolbar. Menu2 fits in the window and doesn't need a scrollbar.

**[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/56Lvpqsb/)**

[image]

```js
$(document.body).on("click", "#menu1", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#bmen").css("display", "none");
  $("#amen").toggle();
});
$(document.body).on("click", "#menu2", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#amen").css("display", "none");
  $("#bmen").toggle();
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.menuwrap {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: black;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.menu {
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
}

.maincontainer {
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 400px;
  background: #c0c0c0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.menu-end {
  padding-top: 36px;
}

.hidden {
  background: grey;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#amen,
#bmen {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 420px;
  display: none;
}

.amen1,
.bmen1 {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 10px;
  top: 36px;
  background: #D3D3D3;
  max-width: 420px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.righti {
  top: 36px;
  background: #CECECE;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.righti ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.righti li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.righti li a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.righti li a:hover {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menuwrap">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">
          <a id="menu1" href="#">Menu1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">
          <a id="menu2" href="#">Menu2</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="hidden">
  <div id="amen">
    <div class="amen1 righti">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">12</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">13</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">14</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">15</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">16</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">17</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">18</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">19</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">20</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">21</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">22</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">23</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">24</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">25</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">26</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">27</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">28</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">29</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">30</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">31</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">32</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">33</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">34</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">35</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="bmen">
    <div class="bmen1 righti">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>



<div class="menu-end"></div>


<div class="maincontainer">
  Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As your code made me go nuts, I am just going to tell you the way to go:
First assure that your body doesn't have a margin and padding set to something, then **PLACE EVERY** menu inside `<div class="maincontainer"></div>`

Then set every menu CSS with `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;` and they would the same thing that my example does.

**Explanation of the CSS of `menu-container`:**

To center (Horizontal) the menu container i used `calc()` (you could use `transform: translate()` too, it would be more dynamic) with the parameter `50% - 400px/2`, this means that the browser would interpret this as "move the element `50%` of the width of the current window to the right and then to the left half the size of the element (Not dynamically as we set the width to `400px`)"

The rest follows the same logic.

*Do a bit of research and try to really understand those answers (I am pretty sure they did answer your problem), this is one of the most common problems people get while learning to develop a web site.*

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu-container {
    left: calc(50% - 400px / 2);
    max-height: calc(100% - 36px);
    max-width: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 36px;
}

.menuwrap {
    background: hsl(0, 0%, 0%) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 36px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="menuwrap">
</div>

<div class="menu-container">
<div class="maincontainer">
Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum 
</div>
</div>
```